# overwriting values in Javascript array does not jive with console output

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is a simplified version of an array of objects that I'm dealing with in a project -

```
let test = [];
test['12/1/2019'] = {k1: 25, k2: 'hello'};
test['1/1/2020'] = {k1: 14, k2: 'bonjour'};
console.log(test);
test['12/1/2019'] = {k1: 16, k2: 'ciao'};
test['1/1/2020'] = {k1: 10, k2: 'good day'};
```

I expected the console output to show this, on account of the `console.log(test);` being before the lines of code that overwrite the original values:
[image]

However, the actual console output is this:
[image]

Why is it behaving this way?

Comment: see that `i` icon in the console log? If you hover it, it will say to you that this log was evaluated at the moment, so it is showing the current value of `test`, not the value of when `.log()` was supposedly called

Comment: What is this running on? If you do this in node and try something like 
console.log(util.inspect(test, { maxArrayLength: null })); you will see the issue doesn't occur.

Comment: @KyleBerezin This is in Vue.js.  I copied/pasted your code in and re-executed but got this error msg: [Vue Warn]: Error in created hook: "ReferenceError: util is not defined"

Comment: @knot22 yea, util is a node package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because JavaScript engine runs every code in batches.

From the code, it looks like `console.log` is called before setting the new values to the array, but in reality, all commands in the current iteration are run first before `console.log` is run in the next iteration.

And because `test` is a reference to a memory location for storing values for `test` array, it now represents the updated value.

The same applies to objects as well.